# problem when clone - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, clone

i am using this [plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/normal.html)

Now i am doing a way to clone the select dropdown. A button to add cloned divs.
So, an user have a initial dropdown, but he can add more. The div is cloned.

The main problem is that when i clone the div, the dropdown is associated to initial dropdown and no to the new, that is cloned. The result is: all dropdowns of the new cloned divs have the event to open the select associated to the first.

[image]

Script to call the plug in

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".mydds").msDropDown();
})

</script>
```

script to clone

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#adicionar').live('click', function(){
            var num = $('.linguas').length;
            var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

            var newElem = $('#copiar' + num).clone(true).prop('id', 'copiar' + newNum);

            newElem.children(':text').prop('name', "myformdata[languages" + newNum + "]").prop('languages', 'languages' + newNum).val('');
            $('#copiar' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#apagar').prop('disabled', '');

        });

</script>
```

Any idea to solve the problem? 
Basically i think the event associated to dropdown is not copied...
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have only one dropdown per cloned element, you can use

```
$('#adicionar').live('click', function(){
    var num = $('.linguas').length;
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

    var newElem = $('#copiar' + num).clone(true, true).attr('id', 'copiar' + newNum);

    var id = newElem.find('select').msDropDown().data('dd').get('id');

    newElem.find('[id]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('id',this.id.replace(id,'customid_' + newNum,'g') );
    });


    $('#copiar' + num).after(newElem);

    newElem.find('select').msDropDown();
});
```

The problem is that the plugin gives an id to the initial `select` element, and uses that id to create other elements and also to refer to its related `select`.

You will need to modify all those ids as well as the reference.. (*the code above does just that..*)

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CXBZR/3/

Comment: chrome, safari and IE8 don't work. only in firefox. Almost :)

Comment: @user455318, updated code (*made it more verbose*) and demo and it seems to work in all browsers now...

Answer (score 1):

In your script you are calling `.clone(true)`. This `true` parameter is cloning the events and data.

From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

> `.clone( [ withDataAndEvents ] )`
> withDataAndEvents: A Boolean indicating
> whether event handlers should be
> copied along with the elements. As of
> jQuery 1.4, element data will be
> copied as well.

If you remove this, or set it to false, this will stop the events from being cloned onto your new divs.

Comment: but i need to clone the events. the problem is that the div is cloned but the event no. If i do what you suggest, only the first dropdown works. I need to clone the div and the event.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. is the event copied or not? In your original question it appears that you are saying it's copied.

Comment: @user455318: No probs. Sorry I mis-understood the question.